# Cannot retrieve array environment variables with `os.environ`

Tags: python, arrays, bash, environment-variables

If I declare an environment variable like:

```
$ export simple_variable="Test"
$ echo $simple_variable
Test
```

I can retrieve it in python with:

```
>>> import os
>>> var = os.environ['simple_variable']
>>> print(var)
'Test'
```

But if I declare an array environment variable like:

```
$ export array_variable=(one two three)
$ echo ${array_variable[*]}
one two three
```

The same python scrit will fail:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.environ['array_variable']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'array_variable'
```

Why? How do I retrieve this array environment variable from my python script?

Comment: tl;dr: You can't export arrays in bash at this time. Find another way of encoding your data.

Comment: @thatotherguy Okay, that's a bad news, but cheers :) Do I remove the post, or will it help python guys more specifically?

Comment: I was answering and somebody close this question... why ? :/

Comment: @BPL Because it's a duplicate, evidently. Consider posting your answer on the other question.

Comment: @Aran-Fey Ah ok, I can see that now because I've reloaded the page, so... it wasn't that "evident" for me when the page wasn't explaining the reason and just showing a disabled "Post your answer" button ;)

Comment: You can leave it to help Google's indexing. Depending on the data you can just export the elements on separate lines with `export foo="$(printf '%s\n' "${myarray[@]}")"` and split it up on the python side

Comment: Also, If you don't need to use the env.var on bash, another alternative would be just something as simple as `export array_variable="(one two three)"`  and split it up on the python side, or even simpler `export array_variable="one two three"`

Comment: @thatotherguy This is what we've ended up doing, cheers :)

Comment: @BPL This is what we've ended up doing, cheers as well :)